# How to custom response for Spring Security if authentication/authorization fail?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm developing a Spring Boot application, using Spring Security to check user login success or user is authorized for access the resource inside.

Right now it's always return 401 Unauthorized whether I input wrong username/password or user is locked. I want to custom it, say if wrong credentials it will return 400 and if user is locked it will return 401.

I have defined custom filter and authentication entry point for the application.

```
public class JWTUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

   ....

   @Override
   public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws AuthenticationException {
        Optional<UserEntity> userEntity = userService
            .findByUserId(request.getParameter("username"));
        if (userEntity.isPresent()) {
           if (userEntity.get().getStatus().equals("LOCKED")) {
              throw new BadCredentialsException("User is locked!"); //I want it to return status 403 here
           }
        }

        String privateKey = userService.findByUserId(request.getParameter("username")).get().getLoginKey();

        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = CryptoUtil.decrypt(privateKey, request.getParameter("password"));

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,
            password, Collections.emptyList());
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        try {
            // Do some process stuff....
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           log.error(ex);
        }
        super.unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed); // I want to return 400 here
    }
}


public class JwtAuthenticationExceptionEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Getter
    @Value("${application.version}")
    private String version;

    @Getter
    @Value("${application.name}")
    private String applicationName;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {

         RESTFulStatus status = new RESTFulStatus(RESTFulStatus.STATUS_ERROR, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(),
            HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase(),
            authException.getMessage(), version, applicationName, Instant.now(), request.getRequestURI());
         log.error(authException.getMessage());
         ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
         response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
         response.setContentType("application/json");
         response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
         response.getWriter().write(mapper.writeValueAsString(status));
    }
}
```

The config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   @Autowired
   private JwtAuthenticationExceptionEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.headers().cacheControl();
      http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
      http.csrf().disable();
      http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint).and()
            .addFilter(new JWTUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtConfig, userService, accessHistoryService))
            .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtConfig)).authorizeRequests();

      http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, jwtConfig.getUri()).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/1/**").hasRole(RoleConstant.ROLE_ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/test/**").hasAnyRole(RoleConstant.ROLE_ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/report/**").hasAnyRole(RoleConstant.ROLE_ADMIN, RoleConstant.ROLE_REPORT)
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
      // If a user try to access a resource without having enough permissions
      http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/login");

      //test in browser
      http.httpBasic();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are extending `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` , you can customise its `AuthenticationFailureHandler` which will be invoked when `attemptAuthentication()` throw `AuthenticationException`.

The `AuthenticationFailureHandler` looks likes:

```
public class MyAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler{

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
            throws IOException, ServletException {


         RESTFulStatus status = new RESTFulStatus(RESTFulStatus.STATUS_ERROR, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(),
            HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase(),
            authException.getMessage(), version, applicationName, Instant.now(), request.getRequestURI());
         log.error(exception.getMessage());
         ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
         response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
         response.setContentType("application/json");
         response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
         response.getWriter().write(mapper.writeValueAsString(status));
    }

}
```

Note:

- Make sure `attemptAuthentication()` will throw `AuthenticationException`
  if authentication fails.
- Make sure you set this customised `AuthenticationFailureHandler` into
  `JWTUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter` during configuration